# workbench access warning message when I click preview

Tags: workbench, entities

Has anybody come across a warning message which appears when you preview content? This message only displays when the workbench access module has been installed and the following setting has been checked 'Require a Workbench Access form element'

The messages:
"*Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in workbench_access_node_form_element() (line 1465 of C:\wamp\www\dev\sites\all\modules\contrib\workbench_access-7.x-1.2\workbench_access\workbench_access.module).*

*Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in workbench_access_node_form_element() (line 1466 of C:\wamp\www\dev\sites\all\modules\contrib\workbench_access-7.x-1.2\workbench_access\workbench_access.module).*
"

Cheers!

Comment: Did you already grant permission for all roles to moderate your contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the related bug [here](https://drupal.org/node/1935190) and the patch [here](https://drupal.org/files/1935190-wa-array-keys_0_1.patch).

You can then download the patch into the `workbench_access` directory and execute

```
patch -p1 < 1935190-wa-array-keys_0_1.patch
```